# I want to publish post in django interactive console

Tags: python, django, post, django-models, django-queryset

Hi I was using django interactive shell and I wanted to create new post as this code.

```
post = Post.objects.get(title="Sample title")

post.publish()
```

but It doesn't work. 
actually, I was following tutorial I have already check code. 
It's definitely same and I've already imported timezone module.

I can check whatever work or not as this code.

```
Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now())
```

and this is my error message

```
post.publish()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Users/cosmian/myvenv/my_site/blog/models.py", line 13, in publish
self.published_date = timezone.now()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

this is my manage.py file

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with your *`manage.py`* file, because according to your post, your *`manage.py`* file seems to be your *`models.py`* file.

Please post your full error code of ***Django interactive console*** so that I could help you out with this.

Comment: Neither your answer nor the comment have anything to do with the question. OP has an instance, he wants to use the method he has defined to set it to "published". He doesn't want to print out the published_date and it's not clear why you think he does.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank You for your guidance, I misunderstand the question

Comment: thank you guys. suddenly It works... I don't know why It works... thanks for everything :)

Comment: I think It is working by restarting the server from the console. if somebody read this question, try to restart server(manage.py runserver) in your console.